# リンクのアドレスを取得したい

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, html5, chrome-extension

拡張機能を作成しようとしています。
リンクを右クリックし、コンテキストメニューに追加した新しい項目をクリックしたときに、リンクのアドレスを取得したいです。

現時点では、右クリックをしたらコンテキストメニューに項目が追加されるようにはなっているのですが、クリックしたリンクのアドレスを取得する方法が分かりません。わかる方いらしましたら、お手数をおかけしますがよろしくお願いします。

現時点でのコードです↓

manifest.json

```
{
"name": "original",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 3,
"description": "This is try",
"permissions": ["contextMenus"],
"background": {
"service_worker": "event.js"
},
"icons": {
"19": "ori_4.png"
}
}
```

event.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: "proto",
    title: "Link Check",
    type: "normal",
    contexts: ["selection","link"],
  });
});
```

Comment: https://github.com/asamuzaK/url2clipboard
参考になると思います

Comment: たすかります。ありがとうございます。